# Bug with returning a value from recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

This was written in answer to a leetcode [problem](https://leetcode.com/explore/challenge/card/august-leetcoding-challenge-2021/613/week-1-august-1st-august-7th/3872/): given a string, return the minimum number of cuts needed to partition the string into palindrome substrings.

It may not be the most efficient way, but I decided to explore the possibilities as a graph, the idea being to only add nodes that can possibly be in a path that creates palindromic substrings. As I build the graph level by level, all I need to do is track which level I am on (0 for root (i.e. the original string), 1 for children of root and so on), and once I hit a node whose value is a palindrome, the current level is the required answer.

The bug I am getting is that instead of returning the `level`, I get a return value of  `None`. The bug only occurs for some inputs. I have tried entering different inputs but cannot see a pattern nevermind determining the cause. Via debugging I know that the return statement is being executed when expected. Why is this happening? What is the problem?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val='', children=None):
        self.val = val
        self.children = children if children else []

class Solution:
    def minCut(self, s: str) -> int:
        if s == s[::-1]:
            return 0
        
        def _create_graph(root, level):
            n = len(root.val)
            for i in range(1, n):
                substr = root.val[:i]
                if substr == substr[::-1]:
                    comp_of_substr = root.val[i:]
                    if comp_of_substr == comp_of_substr[::-1]:
                        return level # code is reaching here as expected, but None is being returned
                    child = Node(comp_of_substr)
                    root.children.append(child)
            for child in root.children:        
                _create_graph(child, level + 1)
            
        root = Node(s)
        return _create_graph(root, 1)
```

I have made sure the code is reaching the return value and terminating there. A sample of the debug I did by print statements:

```
root.val='abccbc', num_cuts=1
n=6
    i=1
    substr='a'
        comp_of_substr='bccbc'
        child.val='bccbc' appended to root.val='abccbc' children
    root.children = ['bccbc']
    i=2
    substr='ab'
    root.children = ['bccbc']
    i=3
    substr='abc'
    root.children = ['bccbc']
    i=4
    substr='abcc'
    root.children = ['bccbc']
    i=5
    substr='abccb'
    root.children = ['bccbc']
root.val='bccbc', num_cuts=2
n=5
    i=1
    substr='b'
        comp_of_substr='ccbc'
        child.val='ccbc' appended to root.val='bccbc' children
    root.children = ['ccbc']
    i=2
    substr='bc'
    root.children = ['ccbc']
    i=3
    substr='bcc'
    root.children = ['ccbc']
    i=4
    substr='bccb'
        comp_of_substr='c'
            found solution with num_cuts=2 # the print statement that gave this is literally
                                           # above the 'return level'
```

Comment: In `for child in root.children: ` you are ignoring the returned level from the recursive call, and below that loop you are exiting the function without returning anything (i.e `None`)

Comment: @trincot That was my first guess, but when I debugged it I printed out what the args immediately at the beginning of the recursive function, e.g. root.val='bccbc', num_cuts=2. The last such printout was the expected one, so I thought that meant I was not calling the function more than I needed. Are you able to give an answer with how to correct this please? EDIT - I just counted the number of calls to the recursive function, it was indeed 2 as expected.

Comment: *"That was my first guess, but..."*: This is not a guess. You get `None` because of this. I didn't analyse your function any further. If you don't want `None`, you will have to have a `return` statement in the case the first `for` loop does not execute the `return` you have there. This is not about *printing*, but about *returning*. You can print what you want, but if you don't return it, you'll get `None`.

Comment: @trincot Thanks, I added the missing line. I still don't see how the bug is caused by what you said. I confirmed that the recursive function is only running twice. I first did it by printing (I know the difference between printing and returning!). As another check after your first comment, I added a property to the Solution class that incremented every time the recursive function was called. I'm not saying you are wrong, but I do not understand why the cause of the bug is what you say. Could you provide some amended code that will fix the issue you mention?

Comment: I will not answer based on your code, because I don't believe this brute force algorithm will finish within the time limits, even when corrected. But just look at your code as it is and ask your self: What will this function return when the first `for` loop finishes and comes to the second `for` loop? Can you point to the line of code where it returns anything? It just isn't there. There isn't a `return` statement there.

Comment: I don't care about whether it will take too long. I care about understanding *why* it is not working. The 'return level' statement is *guaranteed to be hit*, and once it is, no more recursion. So I do not see how it can be what you say. I asked for a code example to help me understand, because you saying "this is the reason..." is not helping me.

Comment: I think you misunderstand recursion. When a recursive call performs `return`, that `return` *only* accounts for the return value of that particular call, and the caller will receive that value. But that caller is in its own turn responsible for returning something to *their* caller. And that is not happening. The second `for` loop is (1) ignoring the value that the deeper call returned, and (2) is not returning anything to its own caller. You say *"...once it is, no more recursion"*: true, but there is still the phase of getting out of the recursion tree. That is where it goes wrong.

Comment: Ok @trincot, I feel I almost get what you are saying. I need to somehow create a chain of returns back up the call stack? A code example would help me better, if anyone could answer.

Comment: Another way to look at it: if you have accumulated a recursive call stack of 3 nested recursive  calls, and the deepest returns the level, each of the pending calls in the call stack will resume their execution (in the second `for` loop where the recursive call was made), but must also return something. So if you have 3 nested calls, you also need 3 executions of a `return` statement. I cannot really post an answer, as your algorithm has several other issues. It is too much to correct, only to arrive at code that may run into a stack overflow or exceed time limit.

Comment: I suggest you try an exercise that needs recursion but is much simpler.

Comment: What is the expected output for `abccbc`? Is it `[ "a", "b", "c", "cbc" ]` where all strings are palindromes? So minimal number of cuts here is 3?

Comment: Oh actually `[ "a", "bccb", "c" ]` with 2 cuts is smaller. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: @Mulan Yep you got it!

Comment: @trincot I 'fixed' it by just returning the result for each child. But yes, I now see some other problems. I fixed those also, removing the recursion. The algorithm I have now gives the correct answer, but it is too slow!

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. Yes, you need a smarter algorithm to make this work within an acceptable time limit.

Comment: thanks trincot for covering some of the issues in the post. i provided an answer which explores the problem from another angle. i don't actually know whether it results in the fewest cuts for _all_ inputs, but in the tests provided the behaviour looks correct. this is a non-trivial problem from beginners, if you have questions, please follow up.

Answer (score 1):

Generators are a good use case for problems involving combinations and permutations. This is because we can easily get a partial or complete answer without needed to modify the search/traversal program. Below we write `palindromify` as a generator which finds all combinations of substrings palindromes -

```py
def palindromify(s, w = ""):
  if not s: return
  if not w and is_palindrome(s): yield (s,)
  yield from palindromify(s[1:], w+s[0])
  if w and is_palindrome(w):
    for p in palindromify(s, ""):
      yield (w, *p)
```

This demonstrates another fundamental programming practice: When you have a complex problem, you can make it easier to solve by solving several smaller sub-problems. Checking whether a particular string is a palindrome is a different task than breaking a string into palindrome substrings. Let's write `is_palindrome` as its own function -

```py
def is_palindrome(s):
  return len(s) < 2 or s[0] == s[-1] and is_palindrome(s[1:-1])
```

Let's see the output of `palindromify` on your input -

```py
for p in palindromify("abccbc"):
  print(p)
```

```py
('a', 'bccb', 'c')
('a', 'b', 'cc', 'b', 'c')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'cbc')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'c')
```

And here it is with a slightly bigger input -

```py
for p in palindromify("abbadeeda"):
  print(p)
```

```py
('abba', 'deed', 'a')
('abba', 'd', 'ee', 'd', 'a')
('abba', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'd', 'a')
('a', 'bb', 'adeeda')
('a', 'bb', 'a', 'deed', 'a')
('a', 'bb', 'a', 'd', 'ee', 'd', 'a')
('a', 'bb', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'd', 'a')
('a', 'b', 'b', 'adeeda')
('a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'deed', 'a')
('a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'ee', 'd', 'a')
('a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'd', 'a')
```

And with a palindrome as input -

```py
for p in palindromify("racecar"):
  print(p)
```

```py
('racecar',)
('r', 'aceca', 'r')
('r', 'a', 'cec', 'a', 'r')
('r', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'c', 'a', 'r')
```

You can see even a small string can yield many possible combinations. And so using a generator here is important because we can terminate the computation as soon as we get the first result. Since the algorithm is written to return the largest palindromes first, it should result in the fewest cuts -

```py
def solve(s):
  for p in palindromify(s):
    return len(p)-1
```

Above `return` automatically halts `palindromes` and no computations happen beyond the first result, potentially saving significant time and space. Now let's see `solve` called on our example inputs -

```py
print(solve("abbadeeda")) # 2
print(solve("abccbc")) # 2
print(solve("racecar")) # 0
print(solve("abcde")) # 4
print(solve("z")) # 0
```

Comment: Thanks @Mulan, I like the approach. Unfortunately it does not seem to work for all inputs, e.g. "aaabaa" it returns 2, instead of 1. I modified it to keep track of the minimum partitions, but of course that meant generating *all* of them and took too long. Question: I get the first 2 lines of palindromify, but what does yield from do as opposed to just yield? Also you mentioned that the largest palindromes should be found first, but for the failure case "aaabaa", the smallest partitioning comes around the middle of the generated solutions. I'm going to try using DP now.

Comment: I was worried there would be some inputs where `solve` fails. `yield from ...` is a way to pass delegation of the generator to another generator; it's what enables you to write recursive generators. notice how `yield` outputs a value where as `yield from ...` is always before another iterable expression. If I get some time later, maybe I'll try to fix it :D